# Connection to MirthDB in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, mirth

I am running Mirth 3.7.1 on a VM within Azure.  The Mirth database is on a SQL Server managed instance within the same Azure subscription.  I have several channels which consume ADT/ORM messages which seem to be working as expected, however, I also have a File Reader channel which reads PDF files from disk and sends them as MDM messages.  This channel is intermittently erroring (see stack traces below) in what appears to me to be with its connection to the Mirth DB.  I am assuming that this is due to the fact that it is attempting to save out the larger file data as it moves through the steps in the channel since the ADT/ORM channels are not having the same issue.  We had this same channel running in a traditional environment and we did not see this same problem.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Also, I have alerts configured to send email when an error occurs.  I am recieving these when the error is within the channel, but I am not being notified of these internal Mirth errors.  Is there any way that I can be notified?

Mike

```
com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.ChannelException: com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.DonkeyDaoException: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.dispatchRawMessage(Channel.java:1213)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.dispatchRawMessage(SourceConnector.java:192)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.dispatchRawMessage(SourceConnector.java:170)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.file.FileReceiver.processFile(FileReceiver.java:354)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.file.FileReceiver.processFiles(FileReceiver.java:247)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.file.FileReceiver.poll(FileReceiver.java:203)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.PollConnectorJob.execute(PollConnectorJob.java:49)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)Caused by: com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.DonkeyDaoException: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.jdbc.JdbcDao.insertContent(JdbcDao.java:274)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.jdbc.JdbcDao.insertMessageContent(JdbcDao.java:193)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.buffered.BufferedDao.executeTasks(BufferedDao.java:110)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.buffered.BufferedDao.commit(BufferedDao.java:85)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.buffered.BufferedDao.commit(BufferedDao.java:72)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.dispatchRawMessage(Channel.java:1185)
    ... 8 moreCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1093)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:563)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:727)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.data.jdbc.JdbcDao.insertContent(JdbcDao.java:271)
    ... 13 moreCaused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:850)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:731)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:114)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.peek(ResponseStream.java:99)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.wait(TdsCore.java:4127)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1086)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor has capabilities to [monitor Azure VM health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-health) but only the following perf counters are included for [Windows VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-health#windows-vms) and [Linux VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-health#linux-vms).

However, [Using Azure Monitor for VMs (preview) Map to understand application components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-maps) there is an ability to create `application maps` that allow you to monitor specific aspects of an application environment and trigger alerts. For example, you can set-up a map for [failed connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-maps#failed-connections) for both processes and connections.